# Repeat notification after time

Tags: android

I want create a notification and it can repeat after time
Here is my code
NotifyService.class

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Context ctx;
private PendingIntent contentIntent;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ctx=this;
    sendNotificationCmt();
}
private void sendNotificationCmt() {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent in = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("hello")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText("des"))
                    .setContentText("des1");

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(2712, mBuilder.build());
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

In MainActivity.class I called :

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(contentIntent);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                2 * 60 * 60, contentIntent);
```

In AndroidManifest I added :

```
<service android:name="NotifyService"/>
```

But it not repeat, What happened in here, please help me . Thank alot

Comment: I had the same problem. I achieved it by following this link. [Scheduled notification ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716989/show-notification-when-xml-item-is-updated/39324437#39324437)

Comment: it delay notification but not repeat when close app

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is you are setting an alarm in `MainActivity` which is getting garbage collected when is closed. Only one alarm that you have set is working.

Google has provided complete tutorial for alarms. Check this link:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html